# Who is liable for material on a website?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, internet

Someone wants to make a website but had trouble registering with the host. He has asked me to do it with my ID. Hypothetically if copyrighted content or something illegal was done with website, who would be liable? The person who the host is registered to, the person who the domain is registered to, the person who uploaded the content, or someone else?

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to never do something that has no upside for you when you have no clue of possible consequences.

Comment: Further to @Jon's comment, I imagine that in many if not most or all jurisdictions (A) the person technically liable in law and (B) the person held liable by lawyers or law enforcement are sometimes not the same person.